# surfaces dominated by  a product of curves

Tags: surfaces

I would like to know for which projective smooth surfaces over a finite field there exists a dominant rational map from a product of curves to the surface

Comment: That is a bit open-ended.  Are you looking for necessary conditions?  Are you looking for sufficient conditions?  Are you looking at a specific class of surfaces, e.g., hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$?  Is there a guess about this problem that you are trying to test? 

Comment: Sufficient/Necessary conditions, counter-examples, references, all will be welcome since I don't know how to attack the question. (I hope that most projective smooth surfaces over a finite field satisfy this condition)

Comment: Well my questions seems to not provoke a lot of enthusiasm! I will be happy enough if somebody give me an example of projective smooth surface over a finite field not dominated by a product of curves.

Comment: non DPC surfaces have been found by  CHAD SCHOEN, Int. J. Math., 07, 541 (1996), VARIETIES DOMINATED BY PRODUCT VARIETIES

Is there a way to characterize non  DPC projective smooth surfaces over finite fields?